# jacoco results differ in jenkins and sonar

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jacoco

I have finally managed to get my builds generate jacoco reports that can be found by both the Jenkins plugin and by Sonar. The problem is that the values they show are different... For the whole code base, Jenkins says 21% lines and 15% branches, while Sonar says 13% and 12%.

From the logs it looks like all exec files are found and the same results should be in both cases.

Is this a known issue or maybe I still didn't get the configuration right? How can I check?

Thanks in advance!
/Vlad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that Sonar automatically filters out the test classes from the results, while the Jenkins plugin has to be explicitly told to do so? With this change, the numbers are almost the same, so maybe it's just rounding errors. It would be nice to get a confirmation, though.

Comment: SonarQube recomputes the code coverage ratio based on its own count of lines of code. Lines of code in test classes are not counted as lines of code.

Comment: Great, then I will be able to sleep well :-) Thanks!

Comment: How did you configure Jenkins to filter out the test classes from the results?

Comment: I didn't. I am just accepting the new values - what matters more to me is the trend, not the absolute value.